# APK Validation service is not available Nokia X

Tags: android, apk, nokiax

i am trying to submit my app to Nokia X app store but when i tried to upload my app to Nokia X app store i got this error:

**Incompatibility**

APK Validation service is not available

**Recommendation**
Please contact publishing support `http://developer.nokia.com/publish/support.`

when i search for this error on nokia developer site: `http://developer.nokia.com/search/results/search&channel=web&limit=20&keywords=APK+Validation+service+is+not+available&category=all/

it says: com.android.future.usb API is not supported Google Play services Nokia X software ... (Not available on Nokia X ... between 2100 and 2133 will fail validation.

**I tried**

1. i signed my app using eclipse > Android Tool >  Export signed apk, 
   validity 800 years
2. i also tried manually creating and signing apk:

create keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore h:\new.keystore -alias new -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 300000
```

sign apk:

```
jarsigner -tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore h:\new.keystore h:\TestApp.apk new
```

verify:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs h:\TestApp.apk
```

align apk:

```
zipalign -v 4 h:\TestApp.apk h:\TestApp001.apk
```

but i am not able to publish my app on Nokia X app store but i have successfully tested my app on Amazon Developer Portal it supports all devices and ready to publish.

why i am getting error on Nokia x app store: APK Validation service is not available.

when my app is successfully signed for 800 years

Comment: Contact Nokia and ask them why their APK validation service is not available. Note, though, that the Nokia X series was discontinued some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget about applicationId "com.my.packagename.nokiax" - in your gradle file?